# How to simulate myopia (near sightedness) in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, photorealism

How to simulate myopia (near sightedness) in Cycles? Inspired by https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/130706.

For anyone with it, it is clear that it isn't a simple blur in post-processing, nor the *default* Depth of Field settings.

I'm assuming I will need to create a spheroid to simulate an elongated eye ball with glass shader, and place the Blender camera where the retina would be.

If the [depth of field setting in Cycles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cameras.html#depth-of-field) is sufficient, what is an approximate table of Focal Distance and Aperture settings for 20/20, 20/40, and so on vision? Is there any other things to *accurately* simulate human vision on earth, like needing a bit of volumetric to make "air".

Comment: So why Depth of Field is not suitable for you?

Comment: As Crantisz said, it could be bossible to enable Depth of field in the Camera settings and change the distance to your desired level

Comment: Hello and welcome.  This question is receiving close votes for lack of detail.  This isn't permanent or a mark against your account, if you [edit] the question it will be automatically queued for review to be reopened.